# Vaporizer not recognized by windows when charging through USB

Tags: usb, battery, charging

I would like to check the voltage (V) and current (A) with which my XMax Starry v3 vaporizer is being charged. I have tried different ports but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Do devices that only charge even show up in device manager? I guess they don't *have* to communicate with windows if they're just charging but then how do I know the V and A? Is there a standard?

Here's the [txt ouput](https://pastebin.com/YrDi1sRY) of a 3rd party tool that displays a lot of useful detail about the USB ports on my PC. The vaporizer was connected to a usb port in the back of the PC (blue, so I think USB 3.0 or 3.1) while this data was collected.

Comment: You need a hardware tool such as this to see how much the vaporizer draws    https://www.amazon.ca/Digital-Voltage-Capacity-Resistance-ET900/dp/B07FMHHS43/ref=asc_df_B07FMHHS43/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=335168096387&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=18391696190432377767&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9000811&hvtargid=pla-569591785109&psc=1

Comment: *Do devices that only charge even show up in device manager?* No, they don't.

Comment: Why exactly are you expecting Windows to recognize this device? A USB must identify itself to the host, if that doesn’t happen, the device can only be charged. Does the specifications on the device indicate it should be recognized by Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are looking at about the devices and usb ports is not detected voltages and currents, but negotiated voltages and currents.

The USB charging standard allows devices to actively negotiate how they get their power by setting a voltage and a maximum current.  The device may pull less current than that as well.

However, the charging standard also allows for passive negotiation (usually by setting resistors) and the results of this will typically not show up in the usb port data, and the device itself won't show up because only active devices with USB descriptors and data functions can be detected.  A passive device would not have a computer chip to send the identity data.